# No idea how to solve this equation using two exponentials

Tags: problem-solving

The equation I have is:

$$A = B ( \exp(C x) - \exp(-Dx) )$$

How do I solve for $x$ given $A$, $B$, $C$, $D$?

I have no idea how. The only idea I have is that I could express these in terms of a taylor series, but is there a better way that I do not know? I could also generate $A$ based on known $B, C, D$ and for a given range of $x$ of finite steps, then find my particular $A$ of interest and see what $x$ was required. (I'm thinking that's a graphical way to attack this.) But it isn't very satisfying.

Comment: I see $A$ as a solution of a linear OE with constant solution.

Comment: Except for very special choices of $C$ and $D$, one cannot expect a "closed form" formula for $x$. A numerical method, like Newton-Raphson, is always a possibility.

Comment: The equation can be rearranged to be $\alpha^x=\gamma+\beta^x$, where $\alpha=e^C, \beta=e^{-D}, \gamma=\frac{A}{B}$.  In this form it is easy to prove that there will always be exactly one solution (so long as $\alpha\neq\beta$).  Finding it is probably something that must be done numerically, as @Andre points out.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Could you explain how one cannot expect a closed form formula for $x$ ?

Comment: Experience. By choosing $C=4$, $D=1$ we get essentially a degree $5$ polynomial equation, for whose solutions there is no nice closed form. Choosing $C=6$, $D=1$ makes things worse. And these are *nice* choices. One may be able to get reasonably quickly converging series solutions. But in general exponential equations, apart from quite special cases, are "algebraically" intractable.